# Magento2 writing Plugins for Interface

Tags: magento, plugins, interface, magento2

I am preparing for Magento Certifications, during practice I came across the following question

**You added a plugin declaration to MyCompany/MyModule/etc/di.xml**

**Please see code declaration below**

What will be the effect of this declaration?

1. An exception because plugins must not be applied to the interfaces
2. An exception because of the syntax error in the declaration
3. The plugin will be ignored because ActionInterface will never be instantiated directly
4. The plugin will be applied to all implementors of the ActionInterface

I know for sure the other 2 attributes (sortOrder and disable) are optional so code is correct syntax wise, also I tried the mentioned code on local there is no exception on syntax error generated while setup:upgrade and di:compile

Need help to find the correct answer here.
Thanks

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface"> 
<plugin name="my_plugin" type="MyCompany\MyModule\Plugin\ActionInterfacePlugin"/>
</type>
```

Answer (score 7):

The correct answer is "4. The plugin will be applied to all implementors of the ActionInterface"

In Magento, the controller must implement the ActionInterface interface. Thus, our plugin will be applied to all classes that implement this interface (i.e., in fact, it is a plugin for all controllers)